# Installing v6 Odin beta together with existing Manjaro and Windows partitions . Setup of EFI boot partition

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, uefi, release-odin

Trying new Odin beta ask for an EFI partition, how should I set up it? I want to keep my Manjaro & Windows boot options alive, too.